# How to redirect page after returning FileStreamResult in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filestreamresult

We have a reporting feature on our site that allows users to download PDF reports of various data.  Some of the reports require parameters, and when this is the case we forward them to a parameter setting view after they choose a report.

After posting the parameters to the server, a FileStreamResult with the PDF is returned.  The problem is, that for reports with parameters, the user is left at the parameter setting page after the FileStreamResult is returned.  I would like to redirect them back to the reports list page.

Is there anyway to do this with the FileStreamResult, or, should I be looking into a custom solution?

Comment: I'm not 100% but I think you might not be able to because you've already sent header data.

Comment: if this isn't something like SSRS then maybe you can open the report in an iFrame so that you don't have to send them back to a page because they never left.

Comment: That makes sense about the header, but, what about sending the redirect prior to feeding the filestream?

Comment: If you do that, how will the stream get started?

Answer (score 1):

you could set the response redirect headers manually before you feed the file although I'm not sure that would work.

How about redirecting back to a "thanks for downloading" page then start the download?

Simon